# How to obtain the "seek to" time in MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using an [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance to play live-streaming videos. When the user seeks forward or backward, I want to obtain the time **to** which the play-head should seek to.

`MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notifies me of a seek event just fine, and `currentPlaybackTime` returns the current time i.e. before seeking. How do I obtain the "seek-to" time without waiting for the next `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying` notification?

Comment: did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Comment: No, I ended up writing my own custom slider